# É possivel criar uma pesquisa interna de um site sem usar PHP e banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, html5

É possivel criar um sistema de pesquisa dentro de um site com javascript e sem banco de dados nem php?

Quero criar um sistema de pesquisa em HTML

Comment: Se todos os dados já estiverem no DOM, sim.

Comment: ne explica melhor, onde posso achar algo que faloe sobre esse assunto, ou qual é o nome desse método.

Comment: de uma olhada em angularJS, isso é muito simples de se fazer caso esteja utilizando um frontend com agularJS.

Comment: Sim, criei isto, é html e javascript normal https://github.com/hatatori/search-engine-system

Comment: Você consegue criar uma busca dinâmica, na mesma página (sem refresh), usando JS puro tranquilamente, da uma olhada neste exemplo da W3 Schools

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim, no entanto, você precisa ter uma fonte de dados. Pode ser um array, um arquivo com os dados que serão usados na busca.

E para tal vcoẽ pode criar usando javascript e html.

Segue um exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<table id="lista">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><div>Nome</div><div><input id="filtro-nome"/></div></th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
            <th>Ramal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ana</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>João</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Luiz</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mário</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rodrigo</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Silvana</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table thead tr {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

table th, table td {
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var filtro = document.getElementById('filtro-nome');
var tabela = document.getElementById('lista');
filtro.onkeyup = function() {
    var nomeFiltro = filtro.value;
    for (var i = 1; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
        var conteudoCelula = tabela.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
        var corresponde = conteudoCelula.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0;
        tabela.rows[i].style.display = corresponde ? '' : 'none';
    }
};
```